# on click show and hide div jquery not working properly in ios device

Tags: html, jquery

`onClick` show and hide div jQuery not working properly in iOS.

I tried this code working fine in android and desktop

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  $(".pdo").click(function () {
    $(".pup").show();
    $(".pdo").hide();
    $(".team").show();
  });
  $(".pup").click(function () {
    $(".pup").hide();
    $(".pdo").show();

    $(".team").hide();
  });
</script>
<style>
  .team,
  .pup {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
```

Above code its not working properly for me then i change this into below code

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  $(".pdo").click(function () {
    $(".pup").addClass('showp');
    $(".pdo").addClass('hidep');

    $(".team").addClass('showp');
  });
  $(".pup").click(function () {
    $(".pup").removeClass('showp');
    $(".pdo").removeClass('hidep');

    $(".team").removeClass('showp');
  });
</script>
<style>
  .team,
  .pup,
  .hidep {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .showp {
    display: block !important;
  }
</style>
```

Above code also not working properly in iOS device.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `touchstart` event instead of either using click event to handle touch interaction

**JQUERY**

```
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  $(".pdo").on("click touchstart", function () {
    $(".pup").addClass("showp");
    $(".pdo").addClass("hidep");
    $(".team").addClass("showp");
  });

  $(".pup").on("click touchstart", function () {
    $(".pup").removeClass("showp");
    $(".pdo").removeClass("hidep");
    $(".team").removeClass("showp");
  });
</script>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
  .team,
  .pup,
  .hidep {
    display: none !important;
  }
  .showp {
    display: block !important;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: touchstart will work on android and desktop device?

Comment: modern desktop devices are there with touch screen support

Comment: to handle both the click and touchstart events to ensure functionality work on all devices

Comment: after adding the code same issue in ios device

Comment: updated code not working properly in ios device

Comment: wrap the jQuery code inside $(document).ready() to ensure that code run after the DOM has been loaded fully and before that verify jquery library is loaded properly